# Lua tables - Can you use it as an array with key?

Tags: arrays, lua, key, lua-table

```
    players={
             {uuid = "abc",name = "TheEisbaer"},
             {uuid= "def",name ="Eisbaer68"},
             {uuid= "ghj",name = "kevin"}
            }
    list={name = "TheEisbaer", name = "Eisbaer68"}
```

With `print(list.name)` it prints "Eisbaer68".
How do I get it to print "TheEisbaer"?

-

Can you do something like `print(players[3].uuid)` or how would one do that?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the name field value corresponding to any uuid field value of "abc"?

Comment: No, I want it to output "true" where the players and the list table are the same and "false" where there are not. If players[2].name==list[2] then true else false, for example

Comment: I think you've got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand (and believe me, it's not easy) what you're trying to do:

First of all:

```
list={name = "TheEisbaer", name = "Eisbaer68"}
```

is equivalent to

```
list={name = "Eisbaer68"}
```

or, more clearly, perhaps:

```
list={}
list.name = "TheEisbaer"
list.name = "Eisbaer68"
```

As you use the same key twice in the same table, the most recent key value overwrites the previous one.

It seems you want to achieve the equivalent of a 'join' in databases.  If you want to display (or, in general, filter) those 'records' from players that have their 'name' appear also in list, maybe something like this:

```
players =
  {
   {uuid= 'abc', name = 'TheEisbaer'    },
   {uuid= 'def', name = 'Eisbaer68'     },
   {uuid= 'ghj', name = 'kevin'         },
  }

list = { TheEisbaer=true, Eisbaer68=true }

for _,t in ipairs(players) do
  if list[t.name] then         --if key exists in list table ...
    print(t.name .. ' => ' .. t.uuid)
  end
end
```

Here the list has keys to make it simpler to lookup.  You could also do it differently but it would probably require a nested FOR loop to go through all possible combinations between the two tables.